# EKS no portainer pod visible in context after helm install

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, portainer

I am trying to deploy a stock portainer app via the official helm chart  https://github.com/portainer/k8s .

I run the following command to install the chart. The target Kubernetes cluster runs in AWS.

```
helm upgrade -i -n sandbox portainer portainer/portainer --set service.type=ClusterIP
Release "portainer" does not exist. Installing it now.
NAME: portainer
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Mar 30 14:07:34 2022
NAMESPACE: sandbox
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
Get the application URL by running these commands:
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace sandbox -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=portainer,app.kubernetes.io/instance=portainer" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].me$  echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:9443 to use your application"
  kubectl --namespace sandbox port-forward $POD_NAME 9443:9443
```

The problem is, when I run the command suggested (kubectl get pods --namespace sandbox) then no pods come up.

```
kubectl get pods --namespace sandbox
No resources found in sandbox namespace.
```

But when I list the services, I can see it:

```
kubectl get services
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
portainer                       ClusterIP   ###.###.###.###    <none>        9000/TCP,9443/TCP,8000/TCP   30s
```

I know I am using the right context:

```
kubectl config current-context
sandbox
```

What am I doing wrong?
Surely I should be able to see pods with:

```
kubectl get pods --namespace sandbox --context sandbox
No resources found in sandbox namespace.
```

I know I am in the right context and right namespace. Any idea what is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is fixed. The problem was that another app called Istiod was in a broken state in the cluster and that prevented kubectl from showing other pods.

```
Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s": no endpoints available for service "istiod"
```